# Existence of Integer Solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exist integer solutions for the equation
>   x^2 ≡ 251 mod 779.
>   [Note that 779 = 19 · 41.]

I know there are properties that can be used when both 251 and 779 are prime but I'm not sure what to do seeing as 779 is composite

Comment: We have $251\equiv 169\pmod{41}$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it for both modulo $19$ and $41$, then conclude by Chinese Remainder Theorem.

> Assume $x^2\equiv251\pmod{19}$ and $y^2\equiv251\pmod{41}$, then there is $z\in\Bbb Z$ such that $z\equiv x\pmod{19}$ and $z\equiv y\pmod{41}$, and then consider $z^2-251$.